# Vagrant set shared folder id?

Tags: vagrant

Is it possible to set the folder id using synced_folders directive? I've tried both of these

```rb
config.vm.synced_folder "../web", "/var/www", id: "web"

config.vm.synced_folder "../web", "/var/www", :id => "web"
```

Apparently these worked on earlier versions. Currently there is no documented option.

I just need to run a "setextradata" command on the folder.

```rb
vb.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/web", "1"]
```

But can't get it to work if the name has a slash in it (and it sets the id to "/var/www"). So either setting the id or knowing how to run setextradata on an id with a slash in it will do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For those who are interested, you can always check the id of the mounted folders with the VirtualBox UI.

You can use that name then in the

```
vb.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/web", "1"]
```

directive.

[image: VirtualBox UI]
[image: VirtualBox UI, Shared folders]